# How do I assign a value to a pandas dataframe cell with a missing value with the value of another cell based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has some missing values. I want to replace those missing values with a value from another cell in the dataframe based on a condition. So the dataframe looks like this:

| x | a |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | A |
| lmn | B |
| None | A |
| xyz | A |
| qrs | C |
| None | B |

What I want to do is set the value of the "None" cell to the value in column x when the values in column a match. So that it looks like this:

| x | a |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | A |
| lmn | B |
| xyz | A |
| xyz | A |
| qrs | C |
| lmn | B |

The index is just sequential numbers from 0 up and may change depending on the dataset so the index for the cells with the missing information will change.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I hadn't tried anything because I wasn't sure what to do. What I thought I would have to do is an if loop where if df['x'][i] == 'None: then take the value of df['x'][j] where df['a'][i] == df['a'][j].  Hopefully that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffill()` to fill forward missing values:

```
df['x'] = df.replace('None', np.nan).groupby('a')['x'].ffill()
print(df)

# Output:
     x  a
0  xyz  A
1  lmn  B
2  xyz  A
3  xyz  A
4  qrs  C
5  lmn  B
```

Comment: I don't know who down voted, but, when I tried this it filled the cells with the None to nan instead of the cell values.

Comment: It worked for your sample. Did you append the `.group(.....`?

Comment: @joanis.  You're probably right :(

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['a'][i] == 'A':
        df['x'][i] = 'xyz'
```

This worked for me, if you want to do all the other letters, just add an `elif`.

Comment: What was wrong with this? It worked for me.

Comment: I feel like this is getting closer to what I need. The only issue is that the there are over 7,000 values in column a, so I need to find a way to identify the "None" cells and use references to replace those values instead of assigning the values directly.